# Oracle TO_CHAR to convert nvarchar to int

Tags: oracle, plsql, type-conversion, to-char

I have a string variable passed to plsql procedure  from front  end which contain  comma selerated integers,  to retrieve  these integers i am using `TO_CHAR (P_LISTID)`. `P_LISTID` is variable  passed.

THIS is working  in many procedures written  by others,  but giving  invalid  number error for me.

Code:

```
Create procedure  p(p_listid in  VARCHAR2)
AS
TYPE IDTYPE TABLE OF TBLFILE%ID. TYPE
FILEID IDTYPE

BEGIN

SELECT *FROM TBLFILE WHERE ID IN (TO_CHAR (p_listid) 
...... 
..... 
End procedure
```

Comment: This is a data conversion: you need to provide a sample of the data , both of the table and the value of `p_listid`.  I could guess what the problem is but I would rather answer a clear question.

Comment: If you have a character string you wish to convert to a number you should use the `TO_NUMBER` function. Best of luck.

Comment: if p_listid is a VARCHAR2 the to_char method would do nothing. Besides, the IN does only work with array types (or multiple parameters).